# Dropdown menu multiple selection by click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to figure out how to make a dropdown menu feature have multiple selection.

Currently I have something like this...

```
<div class="btn-group filter-buttons" id="fDropdown">
   <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default btn-block dropdown-toggle">Events
       <span class="caret"></span>
   </button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li><input type="radio" id="live1" name="feature" value="1" checked><label for="live1">1</label></li>
       <li><input type="radio" id="live2" name="feature" value="2"><label for="live2">2</label></li>
       <li><input type="radio" id="live3" name="feature" value="3"><label for="live3">3</label></li>
   </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).on('click', '#fDropdown', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    (function($){
         var feature = '{{feature}}'; 
         //here feature is the value from the <li> chosen in the dropdown menu
         $('#fDropdown input').each(function(i,v){
            if ($(v).val() == feature){
                $(v).attr('checked', true);
                $(v).change();
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

At the moment, it can only select one value. I'm not sure how to make it select multiple ones **without <kbd>ctrl</kbd> clicking or dragging.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your radio buttons to check boxes:

```
<li>
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="live1">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="live1">
    1
  </label>
</li>
```